# Are relationships still required for linked tables?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

Playing around with MS Access as a frontend I noticed that relationships don't work betweeen local tables and linked ones (ODBC <> MySQL) which makes sense as they are different databases, but testing a form I decided to source them to linked remote tables and they still work fine even after deleting the local Access tables and the relationships I used while creating the form. I used local tables for testing only.

Even without actually creating the relationships inside Access for the linked tables. The local ones required them, but the remote ones don't, form still works. The linked SQL tables do have the proper foreign keys on the server side. My question is why would someone create a relationships inside Access for linked tables or why does the GUI even display that option for linked tables? I don't see a purpose or the reason for having a relationships created in Access for linked tables or is there something in particular that requires them?

Comment: Not required to build relationships even with local tables. Relationships offers enforcement of referential integrity and cascade update/delete. Also, when queries are built, they will assume the links established by Relationships. All of which can be managed without established Relationships. If desired for linked tables, must be established in the backend.

Comment: Review this discussion https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/35e566ed-5d30-47f8-ab10-385661f350c8/understanding-relationship-differences-between-backend-and-front-end

Comment: Do not confuse the tables relation (foreign key) which is a rule for data consistency checking subsystem (it is used by the server when the data is modified) and joining condition which is an expression which sets the rows matching in the query (which is used by the query execution engine which can be either on the server or client side depends on cursor type used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not required. The "settings" or so called Mr. Boss in this regards is of course always the back end database.

So, such "diagrams" really don't matter. However, there is one perhaps "bonus" is that if you do bother to setup in the front end?

Then when you fire up the query builder, and say drop in those 2 related tables, then access will setup and "assume" and draw in the correct relationships in the query builder. Of course the query builder does not "enforce" or really have much to do with "enforced" relationships , but it can be handy. (I mean, you can always build a query - even between say a city column that not even setup as a relationship).

So, the easy way to remember how this works? Well, think what would happen if you had two different front ends - and they had different relation settings? Who would be the boss and which front end would control this?

Answer: none - it is ALWAYS the back end that is the "boss" here.

So, you don't really have to change, setup, or "maintain" the relationships in the front end. They are in effect a pretty picture. However, doing so can sometime help you, since the query builder will see + look at those settings, and guess + setup a relationships by default in the query builder.

but, the simple rule?

The back end is where you "always" must setup the relationships.

Comment: So if I get this correctly, the relationships inside Access are only to make queries easier inside Access? Of course, I don't expect Access to be able to keep data integrity on the server side. My question was more if there is any benefit at all on creating this visual relationships inside Access for linked tables. Assuming here you want to use Access Form/Queries as a management interface. I'm just trying to figure out what is the purpose of that visual builder in Access for linked tables or what it does, as I don't see any difference in my forms.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - they serve no real purpose - and they don't (and can't) change how the data base system will use and enforce those relationships. As a result, setting up, or "drawing" relationships in the front end are only for your enjoyment and pleasure - nothing more, nothing less. As noted, about the only real advantage is that the query builder will use the relationships as defaults if/when you drop in the same tables that exist in that relationships (your pretty picture ). However, other then this issue - no real value exists by creating the relationships in the front end.